# Adding header to PDF file itext java using Alfresco API

Tags: java, itext, alfresco

I'm trying to add a header to a pdf file inside Alfresco using iText in Java, the header will be also a document in Alfresco. I first used Alfresco Content Services REST API to read the input stream for the two files https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/nodes/getNodeContent: nothing updated on the file, any help?
This is my code :

```
                InputStream documentPdfInputStream = getInputStreamForFile(documentUuid);
                InputStream originalPdfInputStream = getInputStreamForFile(pdfNodeUuid);
                ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = getOutputStreamForFile(originalPdfInputStream);
                Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,outStream);
                document.open ();
                document.addTitle("Updated PDF");
                Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(documentPdfInputStream.toString(),new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 25));
                document.add(paragraph);
                document.add(Chunk.SPACETABBING);

                ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfWriter.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(""), 300, 800, 0);
                ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfWriter.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(""), 400, 800, 0);
                document.close();
```

Comment: When i work with content of files i use input and output stream like this:
`//reader
ContentReader reader = contentService.getReader(itemNodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
InputStream doc = reader.getContentInputStream();


//writer
ContentWriter writer = contentService.getWriter(item, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);      
writer.setMimetype(MimetypeMap.MIMETYPE_PDF);
OutputStream out = writer.getContentOutputStream();`

Comment: I'm trying to implement it in my SB App without Alfresco.

Comment: Ok, so then just use GET and after update document PUT endpoint `/nodes/{nodeId}/content`. It should work.

Comment: still not working!